# No additional drivers for ATI Radeon X300 on a Dell Inspiron 6000

Tags: ati, fglrx

Just installed ubuntu 11.10 on my 6year old DELL inspiron 6000 laptop.
I do NOT see any additional drivers for my ATI Radeon X300 card.

I would like to upgrade to ATI proprietary (in my case legacy) driver. 
How do I do it ?
Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a proprietary driver for your X300 card that's compatible with Ubuntu 11.10, which is why we don't offer to install a proprietary driver.

The most recent fglrx driver that supports your card only supports up to X server 1.5.  This was the X server in the Ubuntu 8.10 release - so, three years old.  Attempting to install it will lead only to sorrow.

Answer (score 0):

try this.  click on the system settings (on the unity bar to the left) then when it opens click on additional drivers it will automatically start searching for the drivers.  do not download the post release drivers as I have done so twice and it has locked my laptop up twice and had to reload the system from scratch on another attempt. Let me know if that works.  the name of the driver is: "ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver.